# How can I get year selected in drop down list if drop down list is in php code?

Tags: php, html

html:

```
<select class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-5" name="fromYear" ><?php $starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-50 year'));$ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+4 year'));$current_year = date('Y');$selected_year = date('y',$profile->fromYear);for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) { echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'"';if( $selected_year ) {echo ' selected="selected"'; }echo ' >'.$starting_year.'</option>';}?><select>
```

this code dynamically generates Dropdown for Year. How can I get year selected from the database in this code? for example,if i select 2009 in databse than this code display 2009 as selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do  "**$selected_year = date('Y',$profile->fromYear);**"  please check my code

```
<?php
$starting_year = date('Y', strtotime('-50 year'));
$ending_year   = date('Y', strtotime('+4 year'));
$current_year  = date('Y');
$selected_year = $profile->fromYear; //previosly selected year
?>
<select class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-5" name="fromYear" >
<?php
  for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
     echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'"';
     if($selected_year == $starting_year){
        echo ' selected="selected"';
     }
      echo ' >'.$starting_year.'</option>';
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the selected year as the current year please check my code

```
    <select class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-5" name="fromYear" >
    <?php 
    $starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-50 year'));
    $ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+4 year'));
    $current_year = date('Y');
    $selected_year = date('Y',$profile->fromYear);
    for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++)
    { 
        echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'"';
        if( $selected_year == $starting_year)
        {
            echo ' selected="selected"';
        }
        echo ' >'.$starting_year.'</option>';   
    }
    ?>
    <select>
```

Comment: no i don't want selected year as the current year but i want my previosly selected year as selected year

Comment: if i select 2009 in databse than this code display 2009 as selected

Comment: can you please update you question with your previous year field